# Dynamic DIV does not refresh from AJAX success

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a javascript function that calls a server for JSON and displays the returned data in HTML. I am then deleting a data item via AJAX and then trying to refresh the DIV in the success but this is not working. I also understand that others have encountered the same problem but I am using code that others have used to resolve but to no avail. Can someone please help as this looks so trivial but I just can't get it to work, many thanks in advance for an advice on this bug!

JAVASCRIPT -

```
function getCartData(data){
// console.log(data);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(data.token));
//loop through JSON returned items array
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
     var id = data.items[i].id;
     var title = data.items[i].title;
     var price = data.items[i].price;
     var quantity = data.items[i].quantity;
     var image = data.items[i].image;
     var error = 'error_'+ data.items[i].id;
     var remove = 'remove_'+ data.items[i].id;
//bind JSON object to HTML
     $("#result").append("<div class='column left'><img src="+ image + "width=100 height=100 style=padding:20px></div><div class='column middle' >" + " " + title + " " + price + "</div><div class='column right' ><input id='" + id + "' type=number min=1 max=10 step=1 value=" + quantity + " maxlength=2 size=2 />&nbsp;<br><a id='" + remove + "' class='remove' >Remove</a><div id='" + error + "' class='error'></div></div>");
//load subtotal when page loads
     $('#subtotal').html(data.items_subtotal_price);
}}
//invoke server >> bind to DOM
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = 'https://example.com/cart.json?callback=getCartData'
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

HTML -

```
<div id="cart-container">
<div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

AJAX -

```
$( ".remove" ).click(function() {
var self = this;
var remove_id = $(self).attr('id').replace('remove_', '');
      $.ajax({
      url: "https://example.com/cart/change.json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
      id: remove_id,
      quantity : 0
  },
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //formatted JSON data
      alert('Item removed');
      //TO DO - RELOAD DIV WITHOUT LOADING PAGE
           //  location.reload();
             $('#cart-container').load(document.URL +  ' #cart-container');
  }
});
});
```

Comment: You just seem to reload the cart container, but if you haven't updated it then it will be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that works, I added another div that surrounded the data row -

```
var row = 'row_'+ data.items[i].id; //declare variable then assign to new div row
<div id='" + row + "'>Content HTML...</div>
```

jQuery .remove() in AJAX success -

```
 $('#row_'+ remove_id).remove(); //remove the row
```

Thanks again to all the replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can recall the cart builder function in the success:

```
 success: function(data) {
  console.log(data); //formatted JSON data
  alert('Item removed');
  getCartData(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, I have tried this but it doesn't work, the deleted item is still on the page until I refresh the whole page and then it disappears.

Comment: I noticed now, you should empty the `$("#result")` element

Comment: I tried that but it removed all the HTML and the whole page required a refresh for the data to display again. My solution below is long-winded but it worked.